# Moving from start up screen to loading screen in android app

Tags: android, splash-screen

I set an android startup screen to my app, so that I can move directly after clicking on it to a loading screen (which is a frame animation). The problem is that my app closes directly when clicking on my startup screen. Can you please tell me what's wrong with my program?

Here is my main activity code:

```
package test.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    private ImageView view;
    ImageButton start;
    RelativeLayout background;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startup);
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the XML files i created : 
layout file :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/back"


    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/startup"
        android:id="@+id/startup"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAnimation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the animation file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame01" android:duration="210"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame02" android:duration="210"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame03" android:duration="210"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame04" android:duration="210"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame05" android:duration="210"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame06" android:duration="210"/>


</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the animation inside the ImageView, you have to set background property of the ImageView with your animation file.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageAnimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/animation" />
```

Comment: Thank you, at least now it doesn't stop when I click on the screen but instead it starts directly with the first frame of the animation as a background. The idea was to make the start menu appear and then launch the animation after clicking on the screen.